# Android Toolbar Change Menu action items dynamically

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I have a Toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) and one Action Menu Item on it. I want to programmatically populate submenu for the menu item.
I could not find a way to do it until I set the toolbar as ActionBar by `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`. In this case I can modify menu items in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. Is there a way to change menu items programmatically without `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`?

The only action item is inflated by `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main)`

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always">
 </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the menu of the Toolbar with the Toolbar's getMenu() method. This method returns a Menu object to which you can add or modify menu items, or submenus.

[Here you can check out the documentation of the getMenu() method.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#getMenu())